# How to trigger fabric.js "object:modified" event programmatically?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to fire the 'object:modified' event programmatically. I already tried with "fire" and "trigger" methods.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.on("object:modified", function (e) {
    alert("object modified");
});

var text = new fabric.Text('Text', {
  fontFamily: 'Hoefler Text',
  left: 10,
  top: 10
});

canvas.add(text);

$('.fillText').click(function(){
  text.setFill($(this).data('color'));
  canvas.renderAll();

  text.trigger('modified');
});

$('#moveText').click(function(){
  text.setLeft(50);
  text.setTop(50);
  text.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();

  text.trigger('modified');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gb4u85q4/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can trigger events using `canvas.trigger('<eventname>', options);`. `fire` is deprecated, so you should probably avoid using that.

Since you wanted to trigger `object:modified`, you can do that in the following way, while passing which object was modified:

```
canvas.trigger('object:modified', {target: text});
```

I updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb4u85q4/1/) with the solution added to it. :)
(note that I changed the `alert` to an `console.log` because I find alerts annoying, you can view the output of `console.log` in the developer tools, which can be opened in for example Google Chrome by pressing F12)

Comment: Thanks exactly what i need. How i miss the options parameter? Shame on me :)

Comment: You can also use trigger method without passing object. For example, my project calls a function on any object modified event, so I use trigger method like this: 
canvas.trigger('object:modified')

Answer (score 13):

## Version 4 breaking changes

Meanwhile you should use `fire`.

```js
canvas.fire('object:modified');
```

> In the observabile mixin `observe`, `stopObserving`, `trigger` are removed.
> Keep using `on`, `off`, `fire`. Those are shorter and also all our
> documentation refer to this kind of names.

For more details see [Version 4 breaking changes](http://fabricjs.com/v4-breaking-changes).